# How to detect if handler is an ASIO strand wrap and call it through the strand?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

If there's a generic method taking some handler:

```
template< typename HandlerType >
void Register( HandlerType && handler )
{
    m_handler( std::forward< HandlerType >( handler ) );
}
```

and that handler is going to be invoked through an `io_service` at some point in the future:

```
void SomeEvent( )
{
    // compute someParameter

    m_IOService.post( std::bind( m_handler , someParameter ) );
}
```

How can it be detected if the caller of `Register()` had passed something wrapped by a `strand`, as in:

```
m_strand( m_IOService );

// ...

Register( m_strand.wrap( []( /*something*/ ){ /*...*/ } ) );
```

And how `SomeEvent()` should be changed in order to post the handler through the strand in such cases?

**EDIT**

When I asked this I didn't had the trouble of carefully reading [`io_service::strand::wrap` docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html), more specifically where it says that:

> *(...)* Given a function object with the signature:
>
> ```
> R f(A1 a1, ... An an);
> ```
>
> If this function object is passed to the wrap function like so:
>
> ```
> strand.wrap(f);
> ```
>
> then the return value is a function object with the signature
>
> ```
> void g(A1 a1, ... An an);
> ```
>
> that, when invoked, executes code equivalent to:
>
> strand.dispatch(boost::bind(f, a1, ... an));

And all I need is this indeed - I can just declare `m_handler` as an appropriate `std::function<>` and simply post it through the `io_service` in `SomeEvent()`.

I realized this after reading the answer from @Arunmu, thus I'm accepting it. Nevertheless @Richard Hodges' answer has some good points on ASIO's executors logic and how it was improved in the standalone version.

Comment: standalone asio or boost::asio ?

Comment: @RichardHodges, If there's any difference I would like to know how it is in both cases, but I'm currently using only boost::asio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your requirement clearly, you do not have to do anything out of the way if implemented like below (Read the comments in the code for explanation):

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <type_traits>
    #include <thread>
    #include <memory>
    #include <asio.hpp>

    template <typename Handler>
    class GenHandler
    {
    public:
      GenHandler(Handler&& h): hndler_(std::forward<Handler>(h))
      {}

      template <typename... Args>
      void operator()(Args&&... args)
      {
        std::cout << "GenHandler called" << std::endl;
        hndler_();
      }
    private:
      Handler hndler_;
    };

    template<typename HandlerType>
    GenHandler<std::decay_t<HandlerType>> create_handler(HandlerType&& h)
    {
      return {std::forward<HandlerType>(h)};
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    void SomeEvent(asio::io_service& ios, Handler& h)
    {
      ios.post([=] ()mutable { h(); });
    }

    int main() {
      asio::io_service ios;
      asio::io_service::strand strand{ios};
      auto work = std::make_unique<asio::io_service::work>(ios);
      std::thread t([&]() { ios.run(); });

      // This creates a regular handler which when called by the 
      // io_context would first execute GenHandler::operator()
      // and inside of which it would call the lambda passed below.
      auto hndl = create_handler([] { 
                        std::cout << "Regular Handle" << std::endl; 
                   });
      SomeEvent(ios, hndl);

      ///-------- Example 2 ---------////

      // This creates a handler just like above, but instead wraps a
      // strand handler i.e when GenHandler::operator() gets called
      // it will execute the lambda passed to the wrap in the execution context
      // of the strand.
      auto hndl2 = create_handler(
                       strand.wrap([] { 
                          std::cout << "Strand handler-depth 2" << std::endl; 
                       }));

      // This is a regular strand wrap which is passed to the 
      // io_service execution context. The lambda passed in the strand::wrap
      // would be excuted the execution context of the strand.
      auto str_handler = strand.wrap([=]() mutable { 
                            std::cout <<"strand\n"; 
                            hndl2();  
                          });
      SomeEvent(ios, str_handler);
      work.reset();

      t.join();
      return 0;
    }
```

In the second example the handlers are called in the order as given below:

1. `io_service` is passed the `strand::wrapped_handler`. Therefore, the handler held by the `wrapped_handler` is executed inside the strand.
2. `hndl2` which is `GenHandler` holding another `strand::wrapped_handler` is also called inside of the strand.
3. When `GenHandler::operator()` is called, it executes the held `strand::wrapped_handler` as well. This is done by dispatching the internal handler held by `strand::wrapped_handler` to the strand.

**NOTE:**  For reasons quite unclear to me `strand::wrap` is deprecated. Author wants people to use `bind_executor` instead.

Comment: After reading your answer I realized that the handler returned by `strand::wrap()` will already dispatch through the strand. I feel embarrassed for missing the part of the docs where it says so.

Answer (score 2):

For **boost** asio the answer I think is in this template function:

```
namespace boost_asio_handler_cont_helpers {

template <typename Context>
inline bool is_continuation(Context& context)
{
#if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_HANDLER_HOOKS)
  return false;
#else
  using boost::asio::asio_handler_is_continuation;
  return asio_handler_is_continuation(
      boost::asio::detail::addressof(context));
#endif
}

} // namespace boost_asio_handler_cont_helpers
```

Which if I read it correctly is used to detect whether there is a "context" (i.e. a `strand` or `io_service`) in which the handler is to be executed.

The code in the reactor service then switches based on the result, either executing within the already existing context or not.

In **standalone** asio things have changed somewhat.

There is now a function to detect the context of a handler (if any). I wrote this code after consulting the author.

the relevant lines are:

```
auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(handler, this->get_io_service().get_executor());
```

and..

```
            asio::dispatch(ex, [handler = std::move(handler), future = std::move(future)]() mutable
                 {
// call the user-supplied handler
        });
```

This is production code from "long running task" execution service:

```
    template<class Task, class Handler>
    void async_execute(implementation& impl, Task&& task, Handler&& handler)
    {
        VALUE_DEBUG_TRACE(module) << method(__func__, this);

        using task_type = std::decay_t<Task>;
        static_assert(is_callable_t<task_type, long_running_task_context>(), "");
        using result_type = std::result_of_t<task_type(long_running_task_context)>;
        using promise_type = std::promise<result_type>;
        using future_type = std::future<result_type>;
        using handler_type = std::decay_t<Handler>;
        static_assert(is_callable_t<handler_type, future_type>(), "");
        using handler_result_type = std::result_of<handler_type(future_type)>;

        auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(handler, this->get_io_service().get_executor());

        if (not impl)
        {
            post(ex, [handler = std::forward<Handler>(handler)]() mutable
                 {
                     promise_type promise;
                     promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(system_error(errors::null_handle)));
                     handler(promise.get_future());
                 });
            return;
        }

        auto handler_work = make_work(ex);
        auto& ios = get_io_service();
        auto impl_ptr = impl.get();
        auto async_handler = [this,
                              &ios,
                              impl_ptr,
                              handler_work, ex,
                              handler = std::forward<Handler>(handler)]
        (detail::long_running_task_op::identifier ident,
         auto future) mutable
        {
            assert(impl_ptr);
            VALUE_DEBUG_TRACE(module) << method("async_execute::async_handler", this, ident);
            asio::dispatch(ex, [handler = std::move(handler), future = std::move(future)]() mutable
                 {
                     VALUE_DEBUG_TRACE(module) << method("async_execute::completion_handler");
                     handler(std::move(future));
                 });
            assert(impl_ptr);
            impl_ptr->remove_op(ident);
        };

        using async_handler_type = decltype(async_handler);
        static_assert(is_callable_t<async_handler_type, detail::long_running_task_op::identifier, future_type>(), "");




        auto op = detail::long_running_task_op(std::forward<Task>(task), std::move(async_handler));
        auto ident = op.get_identifier();
        impl->add_op(ident);

        auto lock = lock_type(this->_queue_mutex);
        _ops.emplace(ident, op);
        lock.unlock();

        this->post_execute();
    }
```